# while executing my program it shows syntax error

Tags: bash, shell

```
for i in `seq  0   15 `;
do
b=$(bc -l << EOF
(2.70 + $i * 0.075)
EOF
)
a=`printf "%5.3f"  $b`
```

I am new to shell code.
When I run my program, it shows a syntax error.
Could you tell me what mistake I made?

Comment: It may help if you state the error given to you by the system.

Comment: As a shell script, you've left out the '`done`' which marks the end of a `for ...; do ...; done` loop.

Comment: What's actually the reason for the downvotes here?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a `bash` script (which it seems to be) then there's a `done` missing to close the `for` loop:

```
for i in `seq  0   15 `;
do
  b=$(bc -l << EOF
  (2.70 + $i * 0.075)
EOF
  )
  a=`printf "%5.3f"  $b`
done
```

Comment: @Rafe: I think that makes (at least a bit more) sense. I will change the answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with just `awk` without the need for `seq` and `bc`

```
awk 'BEGIN{
  for(i=1;i<=15;i++){
    b=2.70 + (i * 0.075)
    printf "%5.3f" , b
  }
}'
```